# Handling errors in FluxSink that continuously emits events

Tags: project-reactor

We have a requirement to listen to messages coming off of a Queue and perform a series of operations on the incoming object.

We are planning to use spring reactor framework for this use case, where we can emit the incoming object (from the queue) as an event in a Flux and set up a sequence of map operations on the Flux, that the object flows through to complete the processing.

In order to achieve this, we are trying to use FluxSink as shown below:

```
Flux<ObjectFromQueue> flux = Flux.create(fluxSink -> { 
    messageListener.setFluxSink(fluxSink); 
    //messageListener has a 'process' method that will be invoked as soon as there is a new message on the Queue.
}, FluxSink.OverflowStrategy.BUFFER);

ConnectableFlux<ObjectFromQueue> connectableFlux = flux.publish();
connectableFlux.map(o -> {
        return handler1.handle(o);
    }).map(o -> {
        return handler2.handle(o);
    }).doOnError(t -> {
        errorHandler.handle(t)
    }).subscribe()
connectableFlux.connect();
```

The MessageListener implements a Listener interface(a custom framework class) and overrides 'process(ObjectFromQueue)' method, that will be invoked as soon as there is a message on the Queue and inside the 'process' method, we are invoking

```
fluxSink.next(objectFromQueue);
```

With this configuration we ar eable to achieve our requirement i.e. as soon as there is a message on the Queue, the MessageListener receives the message and the message passes through the configured handler1 and handler2 operators **BUT in case of any error during processing of a message, since onError is a terminal event, the flux stops functioning(i.e emitting to preconfigured operators)**.

What is the best way to overcome this issue? Or is this way of configuring Flux not recommended? If it is not recommended what would recommended way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have two alternatives:

- instead of map use `concatMap` to get a per-value sub-publisher on which you can apply error handling:

  ```
  .concatMap(v -> Mono.just(handler1.handle(v))
                      .doOnError(errorHandler::handle)
                      .onErrorResume(Mono.empty())
  )
  ```

  - in the example above onErrorResume with an empty Mono boils down to dropping the erroring value.
  - since you're still in the concatMap and thus have access to `v`, you could also apply an error handler that returns a default value (but *never* `null`)
- use `handle`: it provides a `sink` that you can skip using if the value should be dropped.

  - typically you would do a `try/catch` and call the error handler instead of the sink in the catch block.
  - you could change your error handler class so that it takes a value, a handler and a sink and it would hide the try/catch. Something like:

    ```
    errorHandler.safeHandle(v, sink, handler1);

    public abstract class ErrorHandler<T> {

        public <V> V safeHandle(T value, SynchronousSink<V> sink, Handler<T,V> handler) {
          try {
            V mapped = handler.handle(value);
            sink.next(mapped);
          } catch (Throwable t) {
            //process error, eg. log or increment metrics
            processError(value, t);
          }
        }

        public abstract void processError(T valueCause, Throwable error);
    }
    ```